# When to use "me or I"

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

I would like to know the correct way to use "me" or "I"

> Please add George and me to the distribution list.

Or is the correct way,

> Please add George and I to the distribution list.

Comment: Hint: Please add George; please add *me.* So, the answer is *me!*

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to remember it, is to think what it should be if it were only you:

> ✓ Please add me to the distribution list.
>   ✗ Please add I to the distribution list.

The correct word is *me*, so that's what you use:

> Please add George and me to the distribution list.